# Change the image of a button that's on a cell upon click

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

In my cell i have 3 buttons, when the user clicks on each button the following 3 method gets fired.

[image]

```
- (void) but1:(id) sender{
    NSLog(@"Touched 1 %ld",(long)[(UIButton *)sender tag]);

}

- (void) but2:(id) sender{
    NSLog(@"Touched 2 %ld",(long)[(UIButton *)sender tag]);

}

- (void) but3:(id) sender{
    NSLog(@"Touched 3 %ld",(long)[(UIButton *)sender tag]);

}
```

Imagine a user clicks on button 1, and then the `but1` method should get fired, and also the background image of button 1 should change. How can make this change in the above method.

NB: I am using `XIB` files.

I was able to access the NIB file that contains the cell .

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil];
        [self.contextMenuTableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

Now how can i access the button he touched and change the image ?

UPDATE

This is a table view. And in each cell there are 3 buttons, I should be able select and deselect one of these buttons in the table.

For example if **only 1 button in the cell can be selected**. When the cell is selected i will show an image. And when it's not i will show the default image.

[image]

Comment: It is normal cell or tableview cell

Comment: what is a normal cell?

Comment: i mean general view. but display like cell.

Comment: @Illep Please share screen shot of your output and expected output. so that i can help you.

Comment: @AshokLondhe I have updated my post. Help

Comment: k.i will try it. wait.

Comment: Have you added this button manually from IB or through coding

Comment: I have added it through IB.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the image of the sender as

```
- (void) but1:(id) sender{
    NSLog(@"Touched 1 %ld",(long)[(UIButton *)sender tag]);
    [((UIButton *)sender) setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
}
```

Good luck

Comment: 1 more thing, How can i change the image. For example when the user clicks for the first time to display `imageA` and then when the user clicks for the second to update it to `imageB`

Comment: Yes, i will. I am still in the process of solving it.

Comment: How can i add TAG to each state of the image. Since there're many rows i end up updating the wrong button in a different row. Help

Comment: The right solution is to subclass UIButton and create your own button and add a state property to it. and check on this state to update your image.

Comment: One important thing missing (in all of the answers actually) is maintaining this state as the user scrolls the table and the cells get reused.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
          UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
          [btnTwo setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: How can i distinguish which button i tapped out of the 3 buttons in the cell ?

Comment: you can get button from cell using tags or you can use "Mustafa Ibrahim" answer as well

Answer (score 0):

To Know which button is pressed you can set Tag for every button. From that tag you will get which button is taped

In interface Section ..

int count;

In viewDidLoad

count=0;

```
- (IBAction)ButtonClicked:(id)sender {



    NSLog(@"Touched 1 %ld",(long)[(UIButton *)sender tag]);
    if(count%2==0)
    {
        [((UIButton *)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageA.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
   {
      [((UIButton *)sender) setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageB.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }


    [(UIButton *)sender setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    count=count+1;

}
```

Comment: How can i change the image. For example when the user clicks for the first time to display `imageA` and then when the user clicks for the second to update it to `imageB`

Comment: You mean everytime when you click the button image get changed

Comment: yes. first time he clicks i display `imageA.png` then the second time he clicks i want to display `imageB.png`. If he clicks again i will display `imageA.png` and vice-versa.

Comment: For that you can check count if it is even then Place  imageA and if it is odd place imageB

Comment: @Illep i have edited my answer please check it and try it. if it work for your case please inform me.

Comment: @Illep don't forget to increment count

Comment: This doesn't work. When i have more rows it doesn't work. `if(count%2==0)` will give the wrong result if i click another row. Can you help me solve it. I have upvoted your answer btw :)

Comment: This answer i only for single row. i don't know that you are using tableview

Comment: Please share your expected output's screen shot

Comment: How can you use a single `count` instance variable to track the state of three buttons for each cell? You need to track the state of every button separately.

Comment: @rmaddy This is only for single button.. and you can do same for another two buttons. i have just given hint

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) but1:(id) sender{

  [but1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  NSLog(@"Touched 1 %ld",(long)[(UIButton *)sender tag]);

 }
```

try this code, this might help you

Answer (score 0):

May be this way you can archive it,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:1] ;
    UIButton *btn2 = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
    UIButton *btn3 = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:3];
    [btn1 setTag:((indexPath.row*10)+1)];
    [btn1  setTag:((indexPath.row*10)+2)];
    [btn3 setTag:((indexPath.row*10)+3)];
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(but1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(but2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(but3:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    return cell;
}

- (void) but1:(UIButton *) sender{
    NSLog(@"Touched 1 %ld",((long)[(UIButton *)sender tag])%10);
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSInteger row = ((long)[sender tag])/10;
    NSIndexPath *indexPathOfYourCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [self.tableview beginUpdates];
    [self.tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableview endUpdates];
}

- (void) but2:(UIButton *) sender{
    NSLog(@"Touched 2 %ld",((long)[(UIButton *)sender tag])%10);
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSInteger row = ((long)[sender tag])/10;
    NSIndexPath *indexPathOfYourCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [self.tableview beginUpdates];
    [self.tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableview endUpdates];
}

- (void) but3:(UIButton *) sender{
    NSLog(@"Touched 3 %ld",((long)[(UIButton *)sender tag])%10);
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSInteger row = ((long)[sender tag])/10;
    NSIndexPath *indexPathOfYourCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [self.tableview beginUpdates];
    [self.tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableview endUpdates];
}
```

Enjoy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
button1.tag = 0;
button2.tag = 1;
button3.tag = 2;
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Add a common selector( `buttonClicked:`) to all the buttons and implement the selector as follows

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [button1 setSelected:NO];
    [button2 setSelected:NO];
    [button3 setSelected:NO];

    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
        [sender setSelected:YES];
}
```